# Positive number validation in jquery

Tags: jquery, validation

I have used an expression for validating a positive number as follows:

```
^\d*\.{0,1}\d+$
```

when I give it an input of -23, it will mark input as negative, but when I give it an input of +23, it will mark it as invalid number!

what is the problem?

Can anyone give a solution that With +23 it will return (positive)?

Comment: not really a jquery question seems to be more about regex

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Have you considered to use anything beside regular expressions?

If you are using the [jQuery Validation Plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) you could create a custom validation method using the [Validator/addMethod](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/addMethod) function:

```
$.validator.addMethod('positiveNumber',
    function (value) { 
        return Number(value) > 0;
    }, 'Enter a positive number.');
```

---

**Edit:** Since you want only regular expressions, try this one:

```
^\+?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+$
```

Explanation:

- Begin of string (`^`)
- Optional + sign (`\+?`)
- The number integer part (`[0-9]*`)
- An optional dot (`\.?`)
- Optional floating point part (`[0-9]+`)
- End of string (`$`)

Comment: thanks ,  my demand is in regular expression and will be striping white space

Comment: this also made me understand regex much better!

Comment: @NazmulHasan '\s' stands for "whitespace character" just add it where you need

Comment: If you are just looking for out of the box positive number validation, you can also look at the answers from user1052072 or Ali Chowdhury below.

Answer (score 19):

Or simply use: `min: 0.01`. 
For example for money

Comment: Like this answer not the best but the smarter!!

Answer (score 4):

Easiest way is

```
$( "#myform" ).validate({
  rules: {
    field: {
      required: true,
      digits: true
    }
  }
});
```

ref : digits method | jQuery Validation Plugin --> https://jqueryvalidation.org/digits-method/

Comment: Also an excelent one, like the answer from user1052072 - it also works, if you just add the ```digits``` class to the input.

Answer (score 1):

Since I'm looking for something similar, this will test for a positive, non-zero value with an optional leading plus (+) sign.

```
^\+?[1-9][0-9]*$
```

This does not match decimal places nor does it match leading zeros.

Answer (score 0):

```
^\+?\d*.{0,1}\d+$
```

Gets you the ability to put a "+" in front of the number.

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on using a regular expression, please make sure that you also capture numbers with exponents and that you allow numbers of the form .42, which is the same as 0.42.

^+?\d*.?\d+([eE]+?\d+)?$

should to the trick.

Comment: it is not my question , my question about + or  - as prefix and should avoid white space

Answer (score 0):

ok, try this;

```
\+?\d*\.?\d+\b
```