# How to client side validate integer

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Basically I want the user of my site (ASP.NET MVC 4) to be able to increase his balance (input in a textbox).
I know how to do that if the integer was an integer of a model, however how can I do it with just a bare integer.

```
@Html.TextBox("Deposit")
```

I want to make sure that when the textbox is submitted, only integers are contained (on client side).
How can I do this without making a model of the integer and writing a textbox for the model attribute?

Answer (score 0):

html5

```
<input type="number" name="Deposit" min="1" max="5">
```

Cant test this right now but somthing like this should cover it..

```
@Html.TextBox(
    "Deposit", 
    null, 
    new { 
        @class = "span1", 
        type = "number", 
        required = "required" 
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascrip/jQuery validation. See this SO question:
[Simple number validation using JavaScript / jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5663141/simple-number-validation-using-javascript-jquery)
and this: [Positive number validation in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090364/positive-number-validation-in-jquery)